# "This database file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Server"

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am currently reading through a book about MVVM and I need to use the Northwind database for the next section. Unfortunately, when I try to add Northwind to my project, I get the following error:

> "An error occurred while connecting to the database. The database might be unavailable. An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.ConnectionUI.SqlDatabaseFileUpgradeRequiredException' occurred. The error message is: 'This database file is not compatible with the current instance of SQL Server.'"

I haven't installed an SQL Server, just Visual Studio 2012. The book instructs me to add the .MDF file to the project, set it as an Entity Data Model, and then to generate from database. It's on the next screen where I get the error. I use NORTHWND.MDF as the data connection and the entity connection string is as follows:

> metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\NORTHWND.MDF;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"

In the book, this reads:

> metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\NORTHWND.MDF;Integrated Security=True;UserInstance=True"

I have tried using both data sources and neither work.

Also of note, the sample code that goes along with the book doesn't work either. It compiles and launches, but in the server explorer, NORTHWND.MDF has an 'x' in the icon and upon launch none of the data is there.

When I attempt to upgrade the database, I get an error saying:

> "Database '...\NORTHWND.MDF' cannot be upgraded because its non-release version (539) is not supported by this version of SQL Server. You cannot open a database that is incompatible with this version of sqlservr.exe. You must re-create the database..."

If anybody could give me any tips on how to get this working, I would certainly appreciate it.

Comment: one way to potentially fix it is, install [sql server 2008 express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) and use database connection to sql server. Do not use local database. That might work. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Nick Your suggestion appears to be working. If you'd like to propose it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to potentially fix it is, install [Sql Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) and use database connection to sql server. Do not use local database. That might work. Just a suggestion.

Also as an extra note, you might want to download SQL Server 2012 *Management Studio* (I believe it comes with the above download as a component that you have select). With Management Studio Installed, you can  test the database connectivity separately, create tables, run queries etc. This will make troubleshooting a lot easier.

Comment: Yes although 2008 will work just fine as well. Also updated my answer. Thanks

Comment: Only SQL Server Express 2012 supports LocalDB. The first connection string will never work with an earlier version

Answer (score 31):

my simple way:

go to VisualStadio 2012
In Server Explorer Windows
open Data Connections
Right click on ASPNETDB.MDF
click on Modify Connection...
a new windows open for you ... you just click OK
if other windows open for you click Yes
FINISH ( be Happy ) :D

Comment: This actually works! I've just updated from Express 2012 mdf to 2016 mdf...Shocking that its been downvoted!

Comment: The same issue for me in VS2015/SQLServer 2014 Express when setting up a test app. Simply clicking OK worked. Thanks!

Comment: This actually still works for VS2017. This should be the selected answer tbh.

Comment: I really do not understand why this is not checked as answer. It worked for me. ;)

Comment: VS2019 is still working! Doing this and run Update-Database command.

Answer (score 4):

If we are trying to attach `.mdf` file in `SQL Express` mode in our development project and while adding `.mdf` file in `App_Data` folder we are getting exception like below :

```
"The database file is not compatible with the current instance of sql server...."
```

Then we can go to `Server explorer` window → go to `Data connections` → go to `"your database"` → right click on `Modify connection` → check the `Data sources` and `Database file name`, then use windows `Authentication` and press <kbd>OK</kbd>.

It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio doesn't install any database server by default so you can't connect to one. The MDF file is just the file where SQL Server stores its data, it's not a standalone database.

You have to install some version of [SQL Server 2012 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) for both connection strings to work.

The first connection string uses the [LocalDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) feature which is essentially a minimal installation of SQL Server 2012 Exrpess (~ 35 ΜΒ). You can only connect to LocalDB from your machine which makes it useful only for development purposes.

The second connection string connects to an actual instance of SQL Server Express, called SQLExpress, installed on your local machine. The second connection string attaches the MDF file to the server as a User Instance, which means that the file is released when you stop using it.

The SQL Server Express downloads range from 130 MB to 1.3 GB depending on which version you download (minimal to full with advanced services).

Answer (score 1):

Northwind database is not readily compatible with 2012, the compatible version of Northwind database for sql server 2012 can be downloaded from the below link, and after downloading .mdf file we can easily attach it with sql server 2012. I have found the following and it helped me, hope it will help you. [How to Attach Northwind Database in Sql Server 2012](http://queryasp.net/download/northwind.zip)

Comment: The link is broken. Found the solution on http://businessimpactinc.com/install-northwind-database/

Comment: And the Download Northwind link on that second link is also broken

Comment: Updated the broken link.

Answer (score 1):

1. First go to data connection as on pic:1

2.Then browser your mdf file  press ok and it will automatically convert the database.

[picture:01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWcyS.png)

[picture:02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5aGN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Modify connection may solves the problem, but I am not sure whether the type of this database file is changed.

I have found a way to solve this problem if you have installed the database Server corresponding to the database file. You just need to change the default database Server of your visual studio.

On the menu, choose Tools-> Options -> Database tools, then on the data connections enter the SQL server Instance name corresponding to your database file which you have installed,then press Ok.

Next step is also important, it is necessary to click 'refresh' or delete the database filename in Data Connection and reopen the file, the file will be added to Data Connection again and open successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. On the Add Connection dialog box, click `Advanced`.
2. Scroll down to the bottom and look for a field called `Data Source`.
3. Change it from `(localdb)\MSSQLlocalDB` to `.\SQLEXPRESS`.